# SSO using Windows Azure Active Dirctory

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-acs, azure-active-directory

i am very new to Active directory and SSO(Single sign on). I have very little knowledge on the same.

I need information how do i start SSO operation using active directory in azure environment.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complete guide on Vittorio's blog: [Provisioning a Windows Azure Active Directory Tenant as an Identity Provider in an ACS Namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/11/07/provisioning-a-directory-tenant-as-an-identity-provider-in-an-acs-namespace.aspx)

1. Create the tenant
2. Add it as an identity provider in ACS
3. Add ACS as an STS in your ASP.NET (MVC) application